# why not display error message in php?

Tags: php

This is my php code for connecting database:

config.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
require_once("constants.php");
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, 5.3, '<') && function_exists('set_magic_quotes_runtime')) set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
$currentPage = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$conn=mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD) or die("sorry! could not connect<br><b>".mysql_error()."</b>");
if($connn) {
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die("sorry! could not connect with database <br><b>".mysql_error()."</b>");
}
?>
```

constants.php:

```
<?php
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost');
define('SITE_DIR', '/selva/');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'mypage1_');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'vkls8');
define('SITE_NAME', 'selva');
define('TABLE_PAGES', DB_PREFIX.'pages');
define('TABLE_TAGLINE', DB_PREFIX.'tagline');
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require("libs/config.php");
?>
```

Now i have entered incorrect database name. but when run this code, it shows nothing. May i know why?. It needs to display 'could not connect with database' right?.. May i know is there any missing in my code.

Can anybody fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because you're output buffering all output, including any error messages you try to display

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: when buffering output, you should ob_end_flush() in the end of script to display output.

Comment: @MarkBaker: If i remove ob_start();, it will shows also nothing

Comment: @deepika maybe you (php user) not allowed to set/change php configuration.

Comment: @prashu: i got it, but most of the website in online, used this one , may i know why? error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

Comment: I used yours  ini_set('display_errors', true);. so it will showed errors.. ok fine. I cleared. thanks.@prashu

Comment: your answer is here: `error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` shows only `errors` not `notice` but `error_reporting(E_ALL);` report all PHP errors. i think [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) will help you.

Comment: @prashu. are you there?

Comment: @prashu: may i know, why we use this $currentPage = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

Comment: this will provide you current page filename without file extension. The second argument to pathinfo() strips the path and extension from the file name (PHP >= 5.2). But in database connectivity you have no need to write this line in your code

Comment: @prashu: how can i  edit sql code after import sql query in database?

Comment: you cannot edit sql code after import. you can edit sql file before import or edit rows after import in [phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin)

Comment: yes.,, i tried it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using this..

index.php:

```
<?php
require("libs/config.php");
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $otuput;
?>
```

OR comment out `ob_start();`